# Почему программа не работает, хотя тег body закрыт?

Tags: html

Имеется данный код, тег body закрыт. Но программа ругается и говорит что не так. Может я что-то не вижу, или это ошибка программы?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>The Life of</h1>
<h2>Coder</h2>
<p><a href="https://www.noisli.com" target="_blank">Плейлист</a> для беспечного занятия кодингом.</p>
<p>Один раз послушал — семь раз покодил.</p>
<img src='https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/free-course/mountains.jpg'alt="картинка на обложке"
     width=230
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Но у вас не закрыт тег `<img>`

Comment: спасибо большое,пол часа голову ломал

Answer (score 2):

Разве редактор кода вам не подсветил ошибку? тег img Не закрыт!
Два варианта правильного написания:

```
<img src="URL" alt="альтернативный текст">

<img src="URL" alt="альтернативный текст" />
```

И картинка-помогатор:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хочется получить бэджик "археолог"?

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли закрыть тег `<img>`